# How to use Java Streams to compare two lists and add common to a field

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two lists `List<Product> products` and `List<AssetMap> mapAssetIds`. Both the `Product` and `AssetMap` classes have two fields `productId` and `assetId`.

```
public class Product {
    public String productId;
    public String assetId;
}

public class AssetMap {
    public String productId;
    public String assetId;
}

List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
products.add(new Product("pid1", "aid1"));
products.add(new Product("pid2", "aid2"));
List<AssetMap> assetMaps = new ArrayList<>();
assetMaps.add(new AssetMap("pid560", "aid1"));
assetMaps.add(new AssetMap("pid3", "aid3"));
```

The output should be:

```
["pid560", "aid2"]
```

I want to check if the `assetId`s in `products` are present in `assetId`s in `mapAssetIds`.

If they are, then take the `productId` from `mapAssetIds` else take the `assetId` from `Product` and put them in a `List<String>`.

How do I do this using Java Stream?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    products.add(new Product("aaa"));
    products.add(new Product("bbb"));
    List<AssetMap> assetMaps = new ArrayList<>();
    assetMaps.add(new AssetMap("bbb"));
    assetMaps.add(new AssetMap("ccc"));

    List<String> commons = products.stream().map(Product::getProductId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    commons.retainAll(assetMaps.stream().map(AssetMap::getAssetId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    for (String common : commons) {
        System.out.println(common);
    }
```

output "bbb"

Comment: It's not what I want to do. I have added an example to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

first create a `map` from `assetMaps` so that `getAssetId` as *key* and `getProductId` as *value*.

```
Map<String, String> map = assetMaps.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(AssetMap::getAssetId, AssetMap::getProductId));
```

then stream over `products` items and find value based on previous result and in case absent value use default value.

```
List<String> result = products.stream()
            .map(Product::getAssetId)
            .map(assetId -> map.getOrDefault(assetId, assetId))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        
        List<String> assestIdsInMap = assetMaps.stream().map(assest -> assest.assestId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        products.stream().forEach(i -> {
            if (assestIdsInMap.contains(i.assestId)) {
                result.add(assetMaps.stream().filter(assetMap -> assetMap.assestId.equals(i.assestId)).findAny().get().productId);
            } else {
                result.add(i.assestId);
            }
        });
```